# MS-Access 2003 CurrentDb.TableDefs("tablename").Connect Database is nothing

Tags: ms-access, vba, odbc, ms-access-2003

So I've inherited this project at work that runs in Access 2003, we're upgrading to a newer version of windows (from Windows Server to Windows 7).

It uses a DSN to connect to our MySQL database, however, Access isn't seeing the database name from the DSN settings.

I already determined the ODBC error, which is as follows: 
[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.6.22-log]No database selected

When I run ?myDB.TableDefs("tblusers").Connect in the immediate window, I get this response:
ODBC;DSN=bnr-rolodex;DATABASE=

I've been wracking my brain for a day or two now and was wondering if anyone else had run into this.

Thanks!

Edit: I should also note that ?CurrentDb.Connect returns blank and highlighting over it has a tooltip saying "Nothing = Nothing"

Comment: My guess is that you set up the DSN via Administrative Tools > Data Sources (ODBC). That is for 64 bit data sources. You need 32 bit, which should be at C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe. Then use the linked table manager to relink the tables.

Comment: try using file DNS adding database name

Comment: The DSN was already set up, and I've tried both the SysWOW64 and the system32 versions of odbcad32. I opened the linked table manager and it's able to see my data source, and I've even created a new one, however, it still doesn't see the database that I selected and just uses the DSN. Unfortunately, I don't have access to a working version of the application, as the old server isn't working currently.

Comment: Annnnd after deleting all the DSNs, rebooting, and adding them again through the linked table manager, it fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AVG solved my question in the comments. The DSN was already set up, but I wound up deleting it

I rebooted after, launched the application, kicked off the Linked Table Manager with this command in the immediate window in VB:

Application.Run "acwztool.att_Entry"

I readded the DSN from there, restarted again and fired access back up and it connected sucessfully! Thanks!